# Check if numbers in JavaScript is in the range of int in Java (–2147483648 < n < 2147483647)

Tags: java, javascript

What's he correct way to validate JavaScript numbers as Java int?

```
  –2147483648 < n < 2147483647

 IsNumeric(2147483648) --> true: which is > int
 parseInt("2147483648") --> 2147483648 : which is > int
```

Comment: Show us some code (function), have you tried something ?

Comment: I tried ($("#field").val() > 2147483647)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test the number in an if?

```
var number = 1234567;
if (Number.isInteger(number)) && number > -2147483648 && number < 2147483647)
{
    console.log("It is a valid integer!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposition, that what I have done to resolve the issue temporary... but I'm looking for more effective solution

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the range of integers in Java is actually "–2147483648 <= n <= 2147483647", the expression `((+a)|0) == a` will work as specified.

- `+a` evaluates the expression a as a number;
- `|0` converts the number to 32-bit integer

The comparison will fail, when `a` is not exactly representable by an 32-bit integer.

Comment: I checked it in jsconsole.com

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do the comparison using `===` since the question specified that the value should be a JavaScript Number, not a string? I do like the bitwise method you're using; I actually came here to add an answer for it if no one else had.

Comment: Yes, `===` can be used for comparison, if the intent is to also guarantee that the variable was originally of number type, not just representable as int32.

Answer (score 0):

as a function :

```
function isValidInt32(number){
   return Number.isInteger(number) && number > -2147483648 && number < 2147483647; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For floating point values, if we want an integer, but allows a value ending in ".0":

```
isInt32(state) {
    if(!(/^([+-]?[1-9]\d*|0).[0]$/.test(state))
        && !(/^([+-]?[1-9]\d*|0)$/.test(state))) {
        return false;
    }
    const view = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(32));
    view.setInt32(1, state);
    return Number.parseInt(state) === view.getInt32(1);
}
```